# Pass function in react native prop

Tags: react-native, dynamic, prop

I currently have a screen that lists items with star ratings on them.

[image]

This is created due to the following JSX being returned by a _renderItem function for a FlatList component. :

```
      <TouchableOpacity
    delayPressIn={70} 
    activeOpacity={0.8}
    onPress={() => {
      navigate("WellbeingBreakdown", {
        id: info.item.id,
      });
    }}
  >

    <RkCard rkType="horizontal" style={styles.card}>
      <Image
        rkCardImg
        source={info.item.icon}
      />

      <View rkCardContent>
        <RkText rkType="small">{info.item.title}{' '}<Ionicons name="ios-information-circle-outline" size={18} color="gray"/></RkText> 


        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', paddingVertical: 10}}>

         <Rating
        type='custom'
        onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
        imageSize={20}
        ratingColor={RkTheme.current.colors.primary}
        ratingImage={STAR_IMAGE}
        style={{paddingVertical: 8}}
        startingValue={2} /*I want to change this to be dynamic */

        />

        <RkButton 
        rkType="rounded small"
        style={{backgroundColor: RkTheme.current.colors.primary, marginLeft: 15}}
        onPress={() => navigate("DynamicActivityAssessor", {
          id: info.item.title
        }) 
      }

        >Assess</RkButton>

        </View>
      </View>
    </RkCard>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

What i would like to do, is dynamically fetch data (from an API) and pass the user's ratings for each item into the startingValue prop of the **Rating** component.

The API if called returns an array. So accessing response[0] gives you an object similar to this (values depending on if its an activity or diet rating etc):

```
{
    "ActivityTotalScore": null,
    "DietTotalScore": 1,



},
```

So i thought a function roughly like so would work, but i can't figure out how to pass it to that prop. Note - info.item.id is the title of the rendered item in question. So it is equal to 'Activity' or 'Weight' etc

```
  getScore(info){

fetch(`${server_url}data/Wellbeing?where=type%3D`+info.item.id, {

    method: "GET", // or 'PUT'  // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error))
    .then(response => {


     return response[0][info.item.id+'TotalScore'] ;

      }
    )
```

}

Comment: just replace the hardcoded startingValue props to info.item.rating (I'm just assuming that the key name is rating based on your info.item.title)

Comment: info is just a local object that is similar to:

  {
    id: "Diet",
    title: "Diet",
    screen: "DynamicActivityAssessor",
    icon: require("../../assets/images/flaticon/diet1.jpg"),
  },

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to create a new Component that representents your card. It could be

```
// In AssessCard.js
import React from 'react';
// Others imports

export default class AssessCard extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rating: 0,
            item: props.item
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadRating();
    }

    _loadRating() {
        fetch(`${server_url}data/Wellbeing?where=type%3D`+info.item.id, {

    method: "GET", // or 'PUT'  // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error))
    .then(response => {
         this.setState({ rating: response[0][info.item.id+'TotalScore'] }); // HERE WE'RE SAVING THE RATING

      }
    )
    }

    render() {
        const { rating, item } = this.state;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
    delayPressIn={70} 
    activeOpacity={0.8}
    onPress={() => {
      navigate("WellbeingBreakdown", {
        id: item.id,
      });
    }}
  >

    <RkCard rkType="horizontal" style={styles.card}>
      <Image
        rkCardImg
        source={item.icon}
      />

      <View rkCardContent>
        <RkText rkType="small">{item.title}{' '}<Ionicons name="ios-information-circle-outline" size={18} color="gray"/></RkText> 


        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', paddingVertical: 10}}>

         <Rating
        type='custom'
        onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
        imageSize={20}
        ratingColor={RkTheme.current.colors.primary}
        ratingImage={STAR_IMAGE}
        style={{paddingVertical: 8}}
        startingValue={rating} // HERE WE USE RATING PROP OF THIS COMPONENT

        />

        <RkButton 
        rkType="rounded small"
        style={{backgroundColor: RkTheme.current.colors.primary, marginLeft: 15}}
        onPress={() => navigate("DynamicActivityAssessor", {
          id: item.title
        }) 
      }

        >Assess</RkButton>

        </View>
      </View>
    </RkCard>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
    }

}

//in file contening your _renderItem function
import AssessCard from './somewhere/AssessCard';
/* CODE */

    _renderItem (info) => {
        return <AssessCard item={info.item} />
    }
```